# Make style changes in notepad++ permanent

Tags: fonts, notepad++, themes, default-settings, fontconfig

When I select a theme and make changes to the font name and font size, they always default back to original settings whenever I reopen notepad++. Is there a way of making font name and size changes to any theme in  notepad++ permanent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run notepad as an administrator; make the desired style changes, save and close notepad++. 
When you open it again, changes should be visible.

Comment: When I do this, my font, for example, renders as Courier New in administrator mode, but when I switch back to the non-admin Notepad, my theme stays the same for everythign except the font...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have administrator rights, changing the entire theme to another theme (e.g. the Twilight theme) is saved permanently even without administrator rights.